# Cast char* to short*

Tags: c++, c

I want to sum up all bytes of my structure. I read that I should cast pointer of my structure from char to short. Why?

Does casting using (short) from char to short is correct?

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pseudo_header
{
    int var1;
    int var2;
    char name[25];
};

void csum(const unsigned short* ptr, int nbytes)
{
    unsigned long sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(struct pseudo_header); i++)
    {
        printf("%#8x\n", ptr[i]);
        sum+= ptr[i];
    }

    printf("%#8x", sum);
}

int main() {

    struct pseudo_header psh = {0};
    char datagram[4096];

    psh.var1 = 10;
    psh.var2 = 20;

    strcpy(psh.name, "Test");

    memcpy(datagram, &psh, sizeof(struct pseudo_header));

    csum((unsigned short*)datagram, sizeof(struct pseudo_header));

    return 0;
}
```

It looks like it works, but I can't verify this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't believe every random thing you read online

Comment: Don't use both [tag:c++] and [tag:c]. Looks like undefined behavior (strict aliasing rule?)

Comment: converting an arbitrary `char*` to `short*` is not guaranteed to work

Comment: @Bathsheba - I don't believe you don't believe me :P

Comment: `sizeof` returns size in units of char. Indexing an array (`ptr` in your loop) moves location ahead by size of what is pointed to (`short` in your code). Since sizeof(char) may not be same as sizeof(short), your code may break as you may end-up moving ahead more than what is pointed to. Also, general C convention/best practice is to move by char, so recommend following it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the behaviour on dereferencing a pointer that's been set to the result of a cast from a `char*` to a `short*` is *undefined*, unless the data to which `char*` is pointing was originally a `short` object or array; which yours isn't.

The well-defined way (in both C and C++) to analyse memory is to use an `unsigned char*`, but be careful not to traverse your memory so as to reach areas that are not owned by your program.

Comment: How to access object representation in C++ may not be that well defined: [core issue 1701](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1701).

Comment: Ok I see, but maybe you can tell me, why in every totorial I saw, programmers performed cast from char* to unsigned short* even the result of this operation is undefined? They didn't know about it? Or maybe there is no another way? You can see here what about I'm talking. https://www.binarytides.com/raw-sockets-c-code-linux/
http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically this works because you cleared the structure with zero. = {0}.
You can give the function a pointer to a structure struct *pseudo_header.

I would see an alignment issue.

I would check sizeof(struct ..) for expected value 33 if I have to add a pragma pack() statement before the structure and then cast to unsigned char* inside the function.

Test your function with a 25 chars length name.

Answer (score 0):

`short` is at least two bytes. So if you want to sum all the bytes then casting to `short*` is wrong. Instead cast to `unsigned char*`.

Comment: Bit of evil pedantry. On a system with, for example, CHAR_BIT set to 64 for example, sizeof(char), sizeof(short), sizeof(int), sizeof(long), and sizeof(long long) can all be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Casting (aliasing) a pointer with any type other than a `char *` violates the strict aliasing rule. Gcc will optimize based on assumptions of the strict aliasing rule and can lead to interesting bugs. Tge only truly safe way round the strict aliasing rule is to use a `memcpy`. Gcc supports memcpy as a compiler intrinsic so can optimize into the copy.

Alternatively, you can disable strict aliasing with the -fno-strict-aliasing flag.

PS - I am unclear if a union provides a suitable way round the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: In C++ you can’t use a union to circumvent strict aliasing. The rule is relaxed in C.